# Finding an object within an array using _id in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection set up that looks similar to this:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64542e42b4c1eebab5ede9c0"),
    user_id: 1,
    user_configs: [
      { _id: ObjectId("645430abf3792ca7853df99a") },
      { _id: ObjectId("645433b0f3792ca7853df99b") }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can easily do a lookup using the parent _id as such:

```
db.test_configs.find({_id: ObjectId("64542e42b4c1eebab5ede9c0")})
```

But I can't find a way to quickly return a single object that lives within that array. This does not return anything:

```
db.test_configs.find({_id: ObjectId("645430abf3792ca7853df99a")})
```

This returns the parent and all the objects inside the user_config array:

```
db.test_configs.find({ 'user_configs._id': ObjectId("645430abf3792ca7853df99a") })

{
  _id: ObjectId("64542e42b4c1eebab5ede9c0"),
  user_id: 1,
  user_configs: [
    { _id: ObjectId("645430abf3792ca7853df99a") },
    { _id: ObjectId("645433b0f3792ca7853df99b") }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to get that single object that lives within the array if I only have the `_id` associated with that object (and not the parent `_id`)?

Edit: Ideally, I'd like to look up the objects in `user_configs` using an `_id` or a form of indexing and I'd like to avoid filtering, if that's at all possible.

Comment: Do you mean something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-cLEdrrTkVf)?

Comment: Not quite. I'd like just the object itself and not the parent object included in the result.

Comment: Something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xmhUieAXd3v)?

Comment: Yeah, that gets the result I'd like but when I check the `executionStats` on it, it's going through all the documents. Is that unavoidable? Ideally I'd like an O(1) lookup.

Comment: Do you have an index on `"user_configs._id"`?

Comment: I don't. Would adding that index resolve this?

Comment: Very likely.  Give it a try.

Comment: I placed an index on "user_configs._id" but still no success. I get the same results I was originally getting:   `{ v: 2, key: { 'user_configs._id': 1 }, name: 'user_configs._id_1' }`

Comment: Your server should do an Index Scan - [mongoplayground.net shows _"IXSCAN"_](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r8WC2mZWpHw).